# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243)

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, spark-streaming

i am getting an error when i am trying to run a spark application with cassandra.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243).
```

I am using spark version 1.2.0 and its clear that i am only using one spark context in my application. But whenever i try to add following code for streaming purpose am getting this error.

```
JavaStreamingContext activitySummaryScheduler = new JavaStreamingContext(
            sparkConf, new Duration(1000));
```

Comment: that's not all the code! did you start the sparkcontext earlier on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only have one SparkContext at a time and since a StreamingContext has a SparkContext in it you can't have a separate Streaming and Spark Context in the same code. What you can do is build a StreamingContext off of your SparkContext so you can have access to both if you really need that.

Use this constructor
`JavaStreamingContext(sparkContext: JavaSparkContext, batchDuration: Duration)`

Comment: Yes, but how I could grammatically retrieve the existing context when submitting a new job?

Comment: The getOrCreate function will let you check if there is a context running in the JVM

Comment: Doesn't work, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722984/sparkexception-using-javastreamingcontext-getorcreate-only-one-sparkcontext-m

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do there

Comment: I just wanted to create a `JavaStreamingContext`; how should I do it instead?

Comment: Start by checking out these https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the second code snippet here
[enter link description here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#initializing-streamingcontext)

This is how your code should look like

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;

JavaSparkContext existingSparkContext = ...   //existing JavaSparkContext
JavaStreamingContext activitySummaryScheduler = new JavaStreamingContext(existingSparkContext, Durations.seconds(1000));
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be as follows:

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Example Spark App").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext jssc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(jssc, new Duration(1));
```